# How to access a locally running django REST project api from android app?

Tags: android, django-rest-framework, android-volley

I have a django REST project which is locally running on my laptop. I am developing an android app to use an api provided by this django project. Both my laptop and android device are connected to the same wifi network. I am using android volly library to access the api. What i have tried is

1. From terminal run `ifconfig` ang got `inet addr`. Let it be `192.168.1.8.`
2. Inside android volly used the url `"http://192.168.1.8:8000/api_part/". (The project is running on port 8000)`

Then the response i am getting from volly is

```
 com.android.volley.NoConnectionError: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /192.168.1.8 (port 8000) after 2500ms: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
```

Am i using a wrong url to access the api? If not then how to acess this locally running project from android app?

Comment: no permissions, firewall, etc. etc.

Comment: @Selvin what? wht are you trying to say?

Comment: Possible reasons

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you start the run server with the correct IP or bind it on all IPs:

```
$ python manage.py 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Comment: actually it solved the problem. but still i am getting 400 as response

Comment: that means that data weren't valid. Print the response content and you'll see what is missing.

Comment: okok. it was beacuse i need to add that to allowed host. now its working fine. Thanks